# Sublimelinter - How to disable window popup on error

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublimelinter

Everytime there's an error, Sublimelinter fires up, marks the error, and intrusively pops out a window showing the first error.

1. How to set it, to just mark the error without popping out the window?
2. How to make it mark ALL errors, instead of just the first one

I'm currently using save-only mode and sublime3 on Ubuntu. I am editing php files

Can someone help? Thanks heaps

And my settings below ...

```
{
    "user": {
    "debug": false,
    "delay": 0.25,
    "error_color": "D02000",
    "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
    "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
    "lint_mode": "save only",
    "linters": {
        "php": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": []
        }
    },
    "mark_style": "squiggly underline",
    "no_column_highlights_line": false,
    "passive_warnings": true,
    "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": []
    },
    "python_paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": []
    },
    "rc_search_limit": 3,
    "shell_timeout": 10,
    "show_errors_on_save": true,
    "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
    "syntax_map": {
        "html (django)": "html",
        "html (rails)": "html",
        "html 5": "html",
        "php": "html",
        "python django": "python"
    },
    "warning_color": "DDB700",
    "wrap_find": true
}
```

}

Comment: This is not a standard behavior, did you configure some odd user settings? Can you append your `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` to your question? To open it select in your menu `Tools » SublimeLinter » Open user settings`.

Comment: I didn't configure anything as far as I remember, so probably it's the default. I have updated the question with my setting

Comment: Background lint mode is the default.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and my lint_mode was set to background. To fix it, go to Tools > SublimeLinter > Show Errors on Save. If that is checked, select it to uncheck it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, to solve it just remove the line:

"tooltips": true

From SublimeLinter » user settings file.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the load/save lint mode. Background mode is much less intrusive. You want `"lint_mode": "background"` in your SublimeLinter package user settings. Then there will be warning and error symbols in the gutter on all the lines with issues.

Answer (score 0):

on your preference.sublime-settings

just put this line

```
"sublimelinter_popup_errors_on_save": true,
```

in order to show all error on a page u need to

ctrl+super+a